# How to shift origin of an arrow in Python OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, graphics, pyopengl

I've written a function to draw an arrow on screen. Now I want to draw it in a specific direction. For the following *vertex_array* it draws an arrow on the screen.

```py
vertex_array = [-0.3, 0.0, 0.0,
                 0.0, 0.3, 0.0,
                 0.3, 0.0, 0.0,
                 0.1, 0.0, 0.0,
                 0.1,-0.5, 0.0,
                -0.1,-0.5, 0.0,
                -0.1, 0.0, 0.0,
                -0.1,-0.5, 0.0,
                 0.1, 0.0, 0.0
                ]
```

[image]

Now how can I write the function to project this array in specific co-ordinate, facing a specific direction?

Like following:

```py
arr = Arrow((from_=(0,0,0),to_=(0.1,0.5,0),color=(200,200,200),alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: It depends on. Do you use "modern" OpenGL and a shader program or do you use legacy OpenGL immediate mode (`glBegin`/`glEnd`) and the fixed function matrix stack?

Comment: using modern OpenGL Should I add rest of the codes here? It contains so many lines though.

Comment: You have to transform the vertex coordinates in the vertex shader (e.g. by a model matrix).